# In Entity Framework 6 with LINQ, how to generate a parameterized IN expression?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

When writing a LINQ query that has a `Contains` call against a precalculated list of values against an Entity Framework 6 `DbContext` (representing a SQL Server database), an `IN` expression will be generated:

```
var ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var query =
    from x in myDbContext
    where ids.Contains(x.Id)
    select x;

// => SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

However, the values are inlined into the query. This means, the generated execution plan cannot be reused and a new plan is generated for every new set of values.

How do you get Entity Framework 6 to generate a parameterized `IN` expression?

I.e., either using a table-valued parameter (I guess this would be `WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN (@p__linq__0)`) or at least individual parameters (`WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN (@p__linq__0, @p__linq__1, @p__linq__2, @p__linq__3)`?

The latter wouldn't be optimal, either, but probably better than a separate query plan for each set of values. (My set is small, 0 to 10 items, so there would be at most 11 different plans. Also, I wouldn't run into the maximum number of parameters per SQL Server query.)

Comment: Use `OR` (`||`) instead, that will be parametrized. You can build the LINQ predicate by using a predicate builder.

Comment: Maybe trial and error is required here to see if we can force different SQL. What does `from x in myDbContext from s in ids where x.Id == s select x` generate? Similarly for a `join`. Also, I was wondering if `ids` is generated like this because it is an array or the `Contains()` method is trying to be smart. Therefore, would `List<int>` give the same results?

Comment: Question is: it is a problem right now? EF is not about performance and do not forget about `parameters sniffing`. Sometimes it is better to calculate execution plan every time.

Comment: @GertArnold Good idea, would you like to post this as an answer, so I can upvote it (and potentially mark as accepted answer unless something even better comes up)?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks for the comment. You're right of course - sometimes, inlined values can be better. However, in other scenarios, parameterized values will be better, so it's still interesting to me how (or if) Entity Framework can do this.

Comment: @DanielDearlove `from s in ids` (or an equivalent `join`) will generate a large construct of nested `SELECT <literal> FROM  (SELECT <literal>) UNION ALL ...` expressions. So, still no parameters, but much more complicated SQL. Also, the collection type (array or `List<int>`) doesn't affect the generated SQL.